# In flutter how to navigate to specific home page based on the type of user logged in?

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement in my application to include two types of users.
one type of user (user_1) will have access to a form page after logging in and the second type (admin) of user will have access to the filled in forms of user_1?
The login screen is the same for both the users. Based on the login credentials, it will be decided whether to navigate user_1 page or admin page.

How to go about this in flutter? To navigate to different home pages for different users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same thing to do.
I use shared preference to know who is the person (in your case an admin or not). Shared preference is a persistent and secured way to stored data. [Here](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) the page of the plug in.

In my initialization page I check the shared preference and redirect to the page depending the result.

```
/// You can put the logo of your app
class LoadingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isLogged(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.beach_access,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future isLogged(context) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String isAdmin = prefs.getBool('isAdmin');
  if (uid == null) {
    /// If it's the first time, there is no shared preference registered
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(...);
  } else {
    if (isAdmin) {
      /// If the user is an admin
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(...);
    } else {
      /// If the user is not an admin
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(...);
    }
  }
}
```

You just have to set up the shared preference when the user connect:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool('isAdmin', true);
```

And don't forget to lunch your loading/initialization screen in your main.dart

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way I use to manage this:

```
void main() async {
  String _defaultHome = "/user_home";
  bool user = await Helper.getLoggeduser();
  if (user.isAdmin) {
    _defaultHome = "/admin_home";
  }

  runApp(App(home: _defaultHome));
}
```

Then in the App class :

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final String home;
  App({
    @required this.home,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample App',
      initialRoute: home,
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Of course, don't forget to import everything necessary.

Comment: How this Helper package works? The official documentation has nothing about this package. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just a class I wrote..  It has a getLoggedUser method that returns the current logged user.. You can add your own logic there